Verify Syntax of STL file
How can I verify if a given .stl file conforms to the syntax requirements of the STL file format?
What is the simplest FOSS CLI tool that I can use on Linux to do a quick sanity check on an .stl file, to know if it's standards-complaint or if it deviates from the standard (eg it's corrupt).
# this command does not exist
stl-tool --check-syntax teapot.stl

Is there some simple tool that I can use to check the syntax of a given .stl file?

See also How to scan and sanitize STL files?

I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to say 3dprinting.stackexchange rather than here. It has nothing to do with graphic design. Also double posting is considered a hard no on stackexhange

Interesting. I'd say it has nothing to do with 3D printing. Questions about .stl files should be relevant to graphic design community, no? Are 3D models not considered graphics? I see lots of other questions on this site about designing 3D objects, including questions specifically about .stl files.

Yes but see this is graphic design not graphics design.  That one 's' changes a lot. Graphic design is the act of conveying messages with visual means. So its not directly about making pictures as such. But yes DCC is not really considered graphic design in general. So 3d pictures are graphics but not nesseserily graphic design. Anyway, this question does not ask about the image but tool to sanitize your programming project. Still 3D printing people ought to know the answer.
